How to dynamically change Navigation Bar color in Flutter based on screen content (e.g., dialogs or night mode)?
Here's the English translation of your request:
I would like the Navigation Bar in my Flutter app to match the colors of my app. The app is mostly white, so I am using the following code in main():
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.transparent,
));

Everything works fine, but sometimes, for example, when a dialog appears, the navigation bar should change to a dark color to match the dimmed screen.

I have a similar problem with my reader, where I want to set a night mode with a dark background. As a workaround, in the reader, when switching to night mode, I also change the navigation bar, but this seems like a poor solution.

you can use Ternary operators.
